# What command in VS Code can be used to go to the next tab in an editor group with wraparound?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code when you're on the last tab in the row and use the "View: Open Next Editor" command, by default it goes to the first tab in the next group. Is there a way to make it wrap back to the first tab?

Answer (score 0):

`View: Open Next Editor in Group`.